# Apache: How to make a per-directory PHP script run when a document in the same directory is loaded

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

The title basically says it all. What I would like to do is when a document (e.g. index.html or picture.png) is loaded from my Apache 2.4 webserver a PHP (PHP version 5.4.29) file in the same directory is executed.

I would basically like it to do the same as the .htaccess file protocol however use a PHP file (which would contain code for lookups etc)

From my reckoning the only way to do this would be to do (using 'customAccess.php' as my file to be executed)

"\index.php" -> "\path\to\file\customAccess.php" -> "\path\to\file\originalPath.php"

Now using this method the idea would be that index.php would point to the customAccess.php with the file to access in the same directory as a querystring which customAccess.php would then forward to. However I would like to stop users from remembering:
"\path\to\file\originalPath.php"
and going straight to this link in the future and therefore bypassing the customAccess.php file. Now I know that I could achieve this by putting an include in my originalPath.php however I would like this rule to apply to other documents like images too and so therefore cannot include other scripts. I'm not very well versed in the usage of Apache configuration but is there a way to force a user to run a PHP script file before continuing on to the original file. The script should be able to stop the whole process if needed.

I realise this is a large ask but I would appreciate any help on the matter,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Try to be very specific. You seem to be trying to merge several queries into one question and thus confusing your audience.

Comment: Ok, here's a more revised attempt:

Is there a way to force a user to run a PHP script before continuing on to the original file. The script should be able to stop the whole process if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to the problem with handlers, although I have read [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_actions.html#action) before, I didn't see:

> It sends the URL and file path of the requested document using the
>   standard CGI PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED environment variables.

After incorporating this I can now reference the requested file in my PHP security script if needed.

Thanks anyway to all of the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Have a require_once at the beginning of every script for your security protocols let's just say you wanted every user to come from a certain IP range.

`path\to\originalScript.php`

```
require_once('\absolute\path\to\security.php');
echo "do awesome stuff here";
```

`\absolute\path\to\security.php`

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(substr($ip, 8) != '192.168.') {
    die('You\'re not on the local network');
    // or do a redirect to a 404 then exit() calmly instead of die.
}
```

This is of course extremely basic but illustrates the point of using includes at the beginning of your files for content control.

EDIT:

For controlling access to non php files. use a handler in your .htaccess file

```
# Files of a particular file extension
AddHandler handler .html
Action handler /absolute/path/to/security.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I would like to avoid doing this as I would ideally like other documents such as .html and .png files to be protected by this rule too...

Comment: Ok I have done that and using your IP example:
security.php
'<?php [Your ip code here] ?>
index.html
'<html><body>TEST</body></html>'
.htaccess
'AddHandler handler .html
Action handler /phphandler/security.php'

And the file is run, but even if the security.php doesn't "die" then the process is still halted, so the index.html doesn't load afterwards anyway

Comment: I may be mistaken about what the handler does.  Have a look at this guy's solution to securing a directory with session variables or cookies. [http://serverfault.com/questions/125579/how-to-secure-a-directory-in-apache-using-a-php-session](http://serverfault.com/questions/125579/how-to-secure-a-directory-in-apache-using-a-php-session)

Comment: I can't seem to get that approach to work... I get an "Internal Server Error" which is usually due to a misconfiguration in the .htaccess file or http.conf. I have used exactly his code (and a few variations of it to see if it would work) with both the files in the same directory however it always returns an error. The error goes away if I remove the RewriteMap and RewriteRule lines from the htaccess file. Am I missing something? Do I need to define the session for this to work, because surely the else statement should handle that?

Comment: I like the handler idea and it seems very close to being ideal for this situation... There should be a way for either the htaccess file or the php file to 'continue' to the original document once it returns

Answer (score 0):

The other option I'm seeing as a valid solution is to have the user log in somewhere, and set a cookie for them.  Then have the htaccess check that cookie before allowing access.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subfolder 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*cookie-name.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /login-error/set-cookie-first.php [NC,L]
```

EDIT:

I knew I had been involved in a project that did something like this.  If you make htaccess check for the existence of the file then that means they had to have successfully logged in instead of spoofing the cookie session.

```
RewriteEngine On
BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ppSD_session=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond /wwwroot/domain.com/www/sessions/%1,1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/login.php?ssg=1&url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/login.php?ssg=1&url=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,R]
```

login.php during a valid login write to the sessions sub directory

```
    create_cookie("ppSD_session","{$session_id}","none");

    $myFile = $options['ppsd_fsp'] . "/sessions/" . $session_id . "," . $this_area;
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Can't write the session files. Login failed!");
    $fwrite = fwrite($fh, '');
    fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Indeed, I've considered this option, however if the user observes his cookies and sees that all he needs is a cookie named xyz with contents abc then he can circulate that, allowing people to fake login cookies.

Comment: @Apples292 I updated the code to include a stronger sense of checking a file exists before allowing access to a folder, you'd put this .htaccess in a sub folder that you want to protect.